# Why the number of adresses stored on RAM is equal to $2^x$ when has "x" adress lines?

Tags: computer-architecture

I know that a RAM when has 20 adress lines can store up to 2^20 data. I don't know the reason. What is that for and how?
[image: image is here]

On the image, where and what is the 2^20?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$2^{20}$ "data" is rather a vague value. If you have 20 bits for address lines you can possibly have $2^{20}$ combinations. If each address line represent 1 bit of data then you've got  total $2^{20}$ bits of data to store in a memory. However most machines store 1 byte of data for every address combination giving you $2^{20}$ bytes or $1$ MB